# Verify mock function is called on button click when using withFormik's handleSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, formik

I have a simple component with some inputs, I am trying to verify whether a mock function is called after a button is clicked.

Here is what I tried in my test file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import AddUser from '../Components/AddUserWithFormik'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import * as Constants from '../actions/actionTypes'

const hist = createBrowserHistory()

describe('AddUser page', () => {
  let wrapper
  const mockFetchDetailsActions = jest.fn()
  const mockHandleCancel = jest.fn()
  const mockHandleInputChangeAction = jest.fn()
  const mockHandleSubmit = jest.fn()
  const match = {
    params: {
      id: '12345'
    }
  }
  const location = {
    pathname: '/add_user',
    search: '',
    hash: '',
    key: 'ph0ovl'
  }
  const user = {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    email: '',
    email_secondary: '',
    mobile_phone: '',
    work_phone: ''
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <Router history={hist}>
        <AddUser
          match={match}
          location={location}
          user={user}
          handleSubmit={mockHandleSubmit}
          actions={{
            fetchDetailsActions: mockFetchDetailsActions,
            handleCancel: mockHandleCancel,
            handleInputChangeAction: mockHandleInputChangeAction
          }}
        />
      </Router>
    )
  })

  describe('#ComponentsRendered', () => {

    it('verify simulate change on all input elements', () => {
      wrapper
        .find('button')
        .at(0)
        .simulate('click')

      expect(mockHandleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
  })
})
```

Here is my component:

```
/* eslint-disable no-invalid-this */
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import GridContainer from './Grid/GridContainer'
import GridItem from './Grid/GridItem'
import { TextField } from 'formik-material-ui'
import { Field, Form } from 'formik'
import dashboardStyle from '../styles/dashboardStyle'
import Card from './Card/Card'
import CardBody from './Card/CardBody'
import * as Constants from '../actions/actionTypes'
import SaveAndCancelButtons from './Common/saveAndCancelButtons'

class AddUser extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    if (this.props.match.params.id) {
      this.props.actions.fetchDetailsActions(Constants.FETCH_DETAILS_API_CALL_REQUEST, this.props.match.params.id)
    } else {
      this.props.actions.handleCancel()
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { classes, isFetching } = this.props
    return (
      <Form>
        <Field
          name="user"
          render={feildProps => (
            <Fragment>
              <GridContainer>
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                  <Card>
                    <h2 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Add User</h2>
                    <CardBody isFetching={isFetching}>
                      <GridContainer>
                        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
                          <Field
                            label="First Name"
                            name={`user.first_name`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                          <Field
                            label="Secondary Email"
                            name={`user.email_secondary`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
                          <Field
                            label="Last Name"
                            name={`user.last_name`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                          <Field
                            label="Mobile Phone"
                            name={`user.mobile_phone`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
                          <Field
                            label="Email"
                            name={`user.email`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                          <Field
                            label="Work Phone"
                            name={`user.work_phone`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                      </GridContainer>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                  <SaveAndCancelButtons
                    handleSave={() => {
                      this.props.handleSubmit()
                    }}
                    routingLink="/people"
                    label="Save"
                  />
                </GridItem>
              </GridContainer>
            </Fragment>
          )}
        />
      </Form>
    )
  }
}

AddUser.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(dashboardStyle)(AddUser)
```

Here is my withFormik() wrapper:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { withFormik } from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import AddUser from './AddUser'
import * as Constants from '../actions/actionTypes'

const styles = theme => ({
  textField: {
    width: '100%'
  }
})

const onSave = props => {
  const userDetails = {
    user: props.user
  }
  if (userDetails && userDetails.user.id) {
    props.actions.updateDetailsActions(Constants.UPDATE_USER_API_CALL_REQUEST, userDetails.user.id, userDetails)
  } else {
    props.actions.addNewUserAction(Constants.ADD_USER_API_CALL_REQUEST, userDetails)
  }
}

const validations = Yup.object().shape({
  user: Yup.object().shape({
    first_name: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    last_name: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    email: Yup.string().required('Required')
  })
})

const withFormikWrapper = withFormik({
  validationSchema: validations,
  enableReinitialize: true,
  handleSubmit: props => {
    onSave(props)
  }
})(AddUser)

export default withStyles(styles)(withFormikWrapper)
```

Expected result:

I expect that the `mockHandleSubmit` is called when the simulate click is happening.

Actual Results:

```
  expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

      123 |       // console.log(wrapper.debug())
      124 | 
    > 125 |       expect(mockHandleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled()
          |                                ^
      126 |     })
      127 |   })
      128 | })

      at Object.toHaveBeenCalled (src/test/AddUser.test.js:125:32)
```

Here is the saveAndCancelButton component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import RoutingButton from './RoutingButton'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import GridContainer from '../Grid/GridContainer'
import GridItem from '../Grid/GridItem'
import ClientContactsStyles from '../../styles/ClientsContactsStyles'
import SaveIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Save'
import Close from '@material-ui/icons/Close'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

class SaveAndCancelButtons extends Component {
  render () {
    const { classes } = this.props
    const close = <Close />
    return (
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
          {this.props.submitButtonProps ? (
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                size="large"
                className={classes.button}
                onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </GridItem>
          ) : null}
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={3}>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            size="large"
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={this.props.handleSave}
          >
            <SaveIcon
              className={classNames(classes.leftIcon, classes.iconSmall)}
            />
            {this.props.label}
          </Button>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={3}>
          <RoutingButton
            variant="contained"
            size="large"
            className={classes.button}
            buttonIcon={close}
            routingLink={this.props.routingLink}
            label="Cancel"
          />
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    )
  }
}

export default withStyles(ClientContactsStyles)(SaveAndCancelButtons)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is jest function is not waiting for formik to call its onSubmit() function. To resolve this jest provides 'wait' api. See the below code.

```
await wait(() => {
  expect(mockHandleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.

But I am still getting the same error. One thing I noticed when I did a console.log(wrapper.props()) before the expect statement is.
I see the handleSubmit function under children.props. 
Maybe this is why the test case keeps failing.

Comment: I tried



``` 
it('verify simulate change on all input elements', wait => { 

```


```

  wait()
      wait = () => {
        expect(mockHandleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled()
      }
    })

```

the test case passes, but the coverage is not reached.

Comment: You should show your SaveAndCancelButtons component as cannot determine if you are clicking the correct button

Comment: @user487779 thanks for the quick responses, I have attached both coverage and SaveAndCancelButton component above.
But I wonder that SaveAndCancelButton have to do something with verifying mockFunction is called or not.
Because I tried  keeping a console log in the onSave method of the withFormikWrapper and did simulate click on the button, I can see the console printed in the terminal
and when I remove the simulate click nothing is printed, that means click and calling of the method is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think submit is being called because your user is not passing your validation.  Rectify that and use below for expectation.

xxxxxx
Given that you have omitted test code in your post that satisfies the schema above is not the solution.  The solution is to do expectations against the actions.  It is not possible to mock handleSubmit as this is dealt with by the withFormik wrapper. 
xxxxxx

```
it('verify simulate change on all input elements', async () => {
  wrapper.find('button').at(0).simulate('click')
  await new Promise(resolve=>{
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(),0);
  })
  expect(mockHandleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: Thank you @user487779, your suggestion for expecting the actions are being called worked. Even test coverage met.